# Find location of a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a hex string in the loaded RAM memory. I am doing the comparison check using if statement. once the string is located I need the location of the string relative to the beginning of the file. RAM is the acquired physical memory of a system

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Could you show us what you have tried so far to achieve this ?

Comment: You need to find string in file or in RAM?

Comment: Does this "RAM" belong to some other application or did *your* app load this file into memory?

Answer (score 0):

[You need the string.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8)

It gives you the index of the start of the string you look for in another string.